# Unable to get $upstream_http_any_custom_header in location directive in nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to log request body based on some custom response header. So, let's say server is sending `TEST-HEADER: value`. Now I have to check the existence of this `header` and do some action on `access_log` in nginx.

My configuration is as below:

```
log_format  test '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                 '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                 '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$request_body"'    
                 '"$sent_http_test_header"';

location / {
        proxy_pass http://app_server$request_uri;   
        access_log  logs/access.log  main;
        set $a $sent_http_test_header;
        if ($a) {
            access_log  logs/host.access1.log  test;
        }
    }
```

Here, the value of `$sent_http_test_header` or `$upstream_http_test_header` variable never get set. So if block never gets executed.

If I use `$status variable`, It works fine.

What could be possibly wrong here??

Comment: Rewrite rules executes before proxying, so at the moment `if` executes there is no `$upstream_...`  variables. You could use nginx 1.7 and `if` modifier of [`access_log`](http://nginx.org/r/access_log) directive.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Is there any way to do in nginx 1.6.0. Because nginx 1.7 is latest release and we are not using in production. We used stable version 1.6.

Comment: I don't know to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Alexey Ten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016033/alexey-ten)  said, `if` runs in the rewrite phase (before content, e.g., proxy), as does `set`. Exactly what you asked cannot be done with nginx 1.6 without extra modules, but you do have two alternatives that may solve your problem:

If you have or can add the lua module to your nginx, you can do:

```
location / {
    set $extra_log dev/null;                                                                       
    # We want the lua code to be run before the log phase, header_filter_by_lua
    # works fine.
    header_filter_by_lua '
        if ngx.header.test_header then
            ngx.var.extra_log = "full_path_without_leading_slash/host.access1.log"
        end
    ';
    # ... the rest of your config ...
    access_log /$extra_log test;  # note / before variable to let nginx know it's
                                  # an absolute path
}
```

Without lua you can use `$sent_http_test_header` in the access_log path, but that will result in the whole value of the header being used for the log file path, rather than just the existence of the variable (and you'll get a log file even if the value is empty). This would look like:

```
location / {
    # ... the rest of your config ...
    access_log logs/$sent_http_test_header.log test;
}
```